# Show that $\phi$ and $\phi \circ S$ have the same positive index of inertia.

Tags: linear-algebra

This problem is part of a problem set of a course on partial differential equations (PDEs), though this problem has no direct connection to PDEs. The solution to this particular problem is used to deduce some properties of a certain type of PDE in one of the other problems in the problem set. I'm doing the problem set in my own spare time, i.e.: not in a university setting.

We are given a symmetric matrix $A \in \Re^{n \times n}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \geq ... \geq \lambda_n$. Let
$\phi$ be the associated quadratic form given by $\phi(x) = x^{T}Ax$,  $x \in \Re^{n}$.
Let p be the number of strictly positive eigenvalues of A (counted according to multiplicity). This number is called the positive index of inertia of $A$ or $\phi$.

Let $S$ be a bijective linear map of $\Re^{n}$ onto itself. We will denote its standard matrix by $S$ as well. Show that $\phi$ and $\phi \circ S$ have the same positive index of inertia.

My approach to this problem is as follows:

$\textbf{Theorem 1}$: If $A$ is symmetric there exists some orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP = D$ with $D$ a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of $A$ on the main diagonal.

$\textbf{Theorem 2}$: If $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices and there is some nonsingular matrix $P$ such that $B = P^{-1} A P$, then $A$ and $B$ are similar.

$\textbf{Theorem 3}$: Similar matrices have the same eigenvalues.

The first thing I do is deduce that since $S$ is bijective it holds that $S^{T} = S^{-1}$ (I am not certain this step holds).

Now, since $S^{T} = S^{-1}$ it implies that $S$ is orthogonal. We know that $p$ is the positive index of inertia of $\phi$. Computing the composition $\phi \circ S$ we get:

$(\phi \circ S)(y) = \phi(S(y)) = S (y) ^{T}A S(y) = y^{T} S^{T} A Sy = y^{T} B y$

So $S^{T} A S = B$. Since $S$ is orthogonal (and nonsingular) we get $S^{-1}AS = B$ and according to **theorem 2** $A$ and $B$ are similar. Then according to **theorem 3** $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues and so $A$ and $S^{T}AS$ have the same eigenvalues. This means $\phi$ and $\phi \circ S$ have the same positive index of inertia.

Is there anything wrong with the reasoning? (for example in the first step where I state the equivalence between $S^{T}$ and $S^{-1}$)

Comment: No, your "uncertain step" is most assuredly false. You're saying that every bijective linear map is an orthogonal transformation. But you *should* write that $S(y) = Py$ for some nonsingular matrix $P$.

Comment: From a book I get: Function $f$ being surjective now means that relation $f^{T}$ is total, and $f$ being injective means that relation $f^{T}$ is functional. From this we conclude immediately that if $f$ is bijective relation then $f^{T}$ is a function from V to B . This function happens to be $f$ ’s inverse, and it is denoted by $f^{−1}$ .

Comment: “This function happens to be $f$’s inverse”? What is this nonsense?

Comment: Anyhow … forget about eigenvalues and look up Sylvester’s law of inertia.

Comment: Part of the point of the problem is to prove Sylvester's law of inertia.

Comment: The change of basis for a symmetric matrix $H$   with basis the columns of some nonsingular $P$  is $P^T H P$   The martrix relation is called congurence

Answer (score 1):

An example with given symmetric matrix $H$  that gradually builds a nonsingular squared matrix $P$ for which $P^T H P = D$ is diagonal. There is no need to force $P$ orthogonal

Algorithm discussed at [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
2 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
3 & 6 & 8 & 9 \\ 
4 & 7 & 9 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
2 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
3 & 6 & 8 & 9 \\ 
4 & 7 & 9 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 3 & 4 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
3 & 0 & 8 & 9 \\ 
4 &  - 1 & 9 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 &  - 3 \\ 
4 &  - 1 &  - 3 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 3 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 &  - 3 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 3 &  - 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 3 &  - 6 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 3 &  - 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 3 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 1 &  - 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
2 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
3 & 6 & 8 & 9 \\ 
4 & 7 & 9 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  - 2 &  - 3 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
4 &  - 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
2 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 
3 & 6 & 8 & 9 \\ 
4 & 7 & 9 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$